# Automatically running a script to read particular information from a .txt file ? (Perl Script, or suggest)

Tags: perl, scripting, automation

**My scenario:** A text file(s) will keep coming into say a folder, I need to detect the new text file, and read particular information from it, say format being (word : info, OR word and under it a column of info, etc.). And, this process needs to keep going on always.

**Problem:** How should I go about doing this, I guess use perl scipt, but where to go from there ?, I am getting ideas, and also help on the internet, but I thought asking it here might make my thoughts clearer.

Kindly help, please suggest a path to do this.

Regards,
Chirayu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: you want a daemon process, so you may want to have a look at [Proc::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~deti/Proc-Daemon-0.09/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod).

Second thing, you need to read & parse your file. Parsing it, depends on its format, and your question is not really clear about it.

Finally, you may want to consider moving a newly detected file (or renaming it) while processing it, end then (possibly) deleting it after having processed. This depends on the requirements that you have. Alternatively, you may want to move the newly detected file into an archive directory after having processed them.

Comment: thanks for replying firstly.
I have not done this before, so I'm in a fix..not a scripting guy really. I am looking at the Daemon process you listed, and wanted to say, w.r.t reading and parsing a file, imagine a text file full of keywords, and I have to parse information listed below that keyword, till another keyword in encountered and the same thing needs to be done.

Comment: @Chirayu: about parsing a file, and processing every line and word, you find useful reading the [Sample Chapter 8: File Contents](http://oreilly.com/catalog/cookbook/chapter/ch08.html) from the Perl Cookbook. You can also find many examples on the Web. When you have some code, you may want to post it, and people on SO can further help you.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to have a perl process that regularly (say every 5 seconds, every 5 minutes or every 5 hours, your call really) scans said directory and as soon as any new text file appears, spawn a child process that process it.

The child process might be another perl script which gets the name of the text file as it's argument and which reads the file, detects the word you mention and then extracts the information you are interested in (and then does whatever you consider necessary with that information).

Things to look out for is what to do with the text files once they are processed.  Are they supposed to stay around?  Then you need to keep track of which of them you have processed, so they do not get processed *again* in the case your master process (the one that scans the directory and spawn perl children) has to be restarted (due to either a crash or a deliberate restart).

If the text files are supposed to disappear once they are processed, then I assume it could be a good idea to either let the children remove them after completion or to let the master process remove them provided the master process always waits for the children to complete before it continues running.  The drawback with a master process waiting for children to complete is that children then cannot be run in parallell but has to be run in strict sequence (not necessary a drawback depending on your situation).

(If you have a master process always waiting for the child process to run, you can actually skip having child processes altogether and create a subroutine in the master program which reads and processes the text file).

High level description but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is the operating system you are using?

On Windows, you can use [Win32::ChangeNotify](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aChangeNotify) and on Linux, you can use [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Linux%3a%3aInotify2) to be notified of changes to the contents of a directory.

Your script can simply wait to be notified and take action when notified instead of polling the contents of the directory which will either waste resources or potentially miss some changes.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of sumthing on the lines of polling only, but am reading on what you suggested..thanks a lot for replying between.
Wanted to ask, how should I go about parsing the text file for a lot of keywords and information ? (I'm not a scripting guy so sorry for asking questions which might read to be stupid).